# C# associate data with other data

Tags: c#

I want to associate different strings [] in a same string [].

My different strings :

- string[] **names**
- string[] **axes**
- string[] **datas**

Every 3 data of **data** corresponds to 3 data of **axes** and every group of 3 data of **axes** corresponds to an only data of **names**. It's in the order.

I want to gather datas which come from different strings.

For example :

- The first data of **names** is : Suj01:RIAS
- The first 3 datas of **axes** are : X, Y and Z
- The first 3 datas of **datas** are (at the first line) : -242.807816,1106.551270 and 1097.119385

(The same schema for the rest)

I want to gather that :

```
Suj01:RIAS
X : -242.807816
Y : 1106.551270
Z : 1097.119385
etc ...
```

The string **names** has only 1 line with 63 items

The string **axes** has only 1 line with (63*3) items (ever X, Y and Z repeat 3 times each)

The string **datas** has several lines with (63*3) items at each line (per line: there is so 63 groups of 3 items, and each item corresponds to an item from axes, and each group corresponds to a name)

How can I do that ?

Here my current programm which allows me to create my different strings as I want :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Recup_donnees_6 : MonoBehaviour {


    void Awake ()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 25;
    }


         void Start()
        {


            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader ("Suj01_PI_DP_C00_1.txt");

            using (reader) { 

                string line = " ";
                int lineNumber = 10;

                for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber; i++) { 


                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line == null) return;
                }

                string line_10;
                line_10 = line;
                string[] names = line_10.Split (new String[] {",",",,,"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                line = reader.ReadLine(); 

                string line_11;
                line_11 = line;
                string[] axes = line_11.Split(new String[] {"Field #",","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

                int counter = 0;
                while (line != null) { 
                    counter++;
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if ((counter %3) != 1) 
                    continue;

                    string lines_datas;
                    lines_datas = line;
                    string[] datas;
                    datas = lines_datas.Split(new string[] {","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Pb : we can't use "Split" when it's a string []

                    line = reader.ReadLine();

                }
            }

    }
}
```

This code runs, it's not the problem.
I just want to show you my current code.

Could you help me, please ?

Thank you

P-s : I'm not english, so I try to write and to mean much as I can.

I do that at the following :

```
        class Axe

        {
            private double x = .0;
            private double y = .0;
            private double z = .0;

            public Axe(double _x, double _y, double _z)

            {
                x = _x;
                y = _y;
                z = _z;
            }

            public double X
            {
                get{return x;}
                set{x = value;}
            }

            public double Y
            {
                get{return y;}
                set{y = value;}
            }

            public double Z
            {
                get{return z;}
                set{z = value;}
            }

        }

        class MyData
        {
            private string aName = string.Empty;
            private List<Axe> axes = new List<Axe>();

            public MyData(string _name, List<Axe> _axes)
            {
                aName = _name;
                axes = _axes;
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get{return aName;}
                set {aName = value;}
            }

            public List<Axe> Axes
            {
                get{return axes;}
                set{axes = value;}
            }

        }

    List<MyAData> datas = new List<MyData>();

    for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)

    {
        var myClassVar = new MyData();
        myClassVar.name = names[i];
        myClassVar.axisX = axes[(i*3)];
        myClassVar.axisY = axes[(i*3)+1];
        myClassVar.axisZ = axes[(i*3)+2];
        myClassVar.dataA = datas[(i*3)];
        myClassVar.dataB = datas[(i*3)+1];
        myClassVar.dataC = datas[(i*3)+2];
        listOfAwesome.Add(myClassVar);

    }
```

Comment: Instead of maintaining 3 arrays, you would be much better maintaining one array of `MyOwnAmazingClassName` which has 3 properties

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining 3 arrays, just create your own object that has some meaningful parameter names that you can then append items to.. The below should work but you might need to do some extra validation to make sure `axes` and `datas` lengths are the right size..

```
List<MyAwesomeClass> listOfAwesome = new List<MyAwesomeClass>();
for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    var myClassVar = new MyAwesomeClass();
    myClassVar.name = names[i];
    myClassVar.axisX = axes[(i*3)];
    myClassVar.axisY = axes[(i*3)+1];
    myClassVar.axisZ = axes[(i*3)+2];
    myClassVar.dataA = datas[(i*3)];
    myClassVar.dataB = datas[(i*3)+1];
    myClassVar.dataC = datas[(i*3)+2];
    listOfAwesome.Add(myClassVar);
}
```

---

Full code:

```
 void Start()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader ("Suj01_PI_DP_C00_1.txt"))
    { 
        string line = " ";
        int lineNumber = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < lineNumber; i++) 
        { 
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null) return;
        }

        string[] names = line.Split (new String[] {",",",,,"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        string line_11 = reader.ReadLine();;
        string[] axes = line_11.Split(new String[] {"Field #",","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

        int counter = 0;
        while (line != null) { 
            counter++;
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            if ((counter %3) != 1) 
                continue;

            string lines_datas;
            lines_datas = line;
            string[] datas;
            datas = lines_datas.Split(new string[] {","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Pb : we can't use "Split" when it's a string []

            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }

        List<MyAwesomeClass> listOfAwesome = new List<MyAwesomeClass>();
        for(int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            var myClassVar = new MyAwesomeClass();
            myClassVar.name = names[i];
            myClassVar.axisX = axes[(i*3)];
            myClassVar.axisY = axes[(i*3)+1];
            myClassVar.axisZ = axes[(i*3)+2];
            myClassVar.dataA = datas[(i*3)];
            myClassVar.dataB = datas[(i*3)+1];
            myClassVar.dataC = datas[(i*3)+2];
            listOfAwesome.Add(myClassVar);
        }           
    }
```

---

Edit:

An example of `MyAwesomeClass` would be

```
public class MyAwesomeClass
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string AxisX {get;set;}
    public string AxisY {get;set;}
    public string AxisZ {get;set;}
    public string DataA {get;set;}
    public string DataB {get;set;}
    public string DataC {get;set;}

    public MyAwesomeClass()
    {
    }
}
```

But you should expand upon this to change the types of each value accordingly. You can find out more about classes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/x9afc042.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much to do this code.

Does this code do it for every line of datas ?
Or I have to do a loop for this parameter ?

Thank you very much again !

Comment: @Coralie - In the full code you can see at the end I create a list of objects from all the data you have collected, however you will still need to first design your own class

Comment: I have edited my question to show you what I do for the code. Is it correct ? I'm lost !

Comment: @Coralie - What you have looks correct but as a first step I would try to introduce the code I have in this answer first before extending further. Your `MyData` would just have an `Axe` instead of a list for example. The code in this answer can be used to replace your `Start` method, and then if you set a breakpoint at the end of that method, you will see you have a list of objects that you can do what you want with